# Compare two values in rows by key and then conditionally add something to table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

At that moment in classes we've learned only simple Selects, Inner Joins, entering data in tables etc. But now I need to do some complex function.

I have database of soccer matches. I have table Matches:

```
ID; ID_Country_1; Id_Country_2; Date; Group
```

And with help of Stackoverflow now I have second table of goals:

```
ID; Group; Country; Date; Goals
```

For example, here's rows like this:

```
1; Russia; Canada; date; A
```

```
1; A; Russia; date; 0 goals
1; A; Canada; date; 3 goals
```

And what I want is to go by one Id (f.e 1) and compare who scored more goals and then with knowing this information create new table with Points (3 for w and e.t.c). I did table when I have:

```
Country1 - Contry2; Score1-Score2;
```

But then realized that it's completely useless and now I have to parse stuff, and denied this idea. Like, I don't have any idea how to do it, what should I use, maybe what should I read or check, or maybe some examples you can have, without binding it to code, just in general how to organize my selects and etc.
P.S: It's SQL 17 and SMSS. 
Desired output smth like that:

```
IDCountry; Points; (Maybe) Goals in general
IDCountry; Points; (Maybe) Goals in general
Example:
Russia; 4; 4;
Canada; 6; 3
```

Note: I have many rows with games, so its not just select top(1), its for all rows. Also sorry for my bad English :)
I would appreciate if someone just write general example for cases like that, and I will build it into my database while googling stuff

Comment: Please include the exact desired output.

Comment: I tried to do this table with "-" between, and stucked understanding I have no idea how to write functions, variables and e.t.c. Like I can easy write something like that on c#, python, but here I'm working in SQL17 and SSMS.

Comment: lIke, i did this table with "-" but then realized I don't need it.

Comment: I can write my code for this table but it goes with russian words and I don't think its would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to get you started with one idea/method:

You can join the goals table to itself so you'll be able to specify winner/loser **untested**

```
select g1.ID as Match, g1.Country,
   case when g1.goals > g2.goals then 3  -- this case statement will get you the points for win/tie/loss
        when g1.goals = g2.goals then 1  -- tie
        else 0  -- loss
   end AS PointsFromThisMatch,
   g1.goals as GoalsInThisMatch
from goals g1 -- The goals table, this will be the target of the points
inner join goals g2 -- The goals table again, this will be the opponent to determine win/lose/tie
   on g1.ID = g2.ID -- The same match
   and g1.country <> g2.country -- avoid joining a row to itself
```

That should return the points and goals for each team for each match.  Those results can then be summed together for each team:

```
select t1.Country, sum(PointsFromThisMatch) TotalPoints,
   sum(GoalsInThisMatch) TotalGoalsScored
from (
   select g1.ID as Match, g1.Country,
      case when g1.goals > g2.goals then 3
           when g1.goals = g2.goals then 1
           else 0
      end AS PointsFromThisMatch,
      g1.goals as GoalsInThisMatch
   from goals g1
   inner join goals g2
      on g1.ID = g2.ID
      and g1.country <> g2.country
) t1
group by t1.Country
```